# what does syntax .= means in perl

Tags: perl, syntax

I came across a Perl script which uses following .= syntax

```
$key .= $descriptions[$i];
```

what does .= means here

Comment: If you have further questions about Perl that isn't really about how to use the language on Unix sytems, then [the StackOverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/) may be a better fit for those questions.

Answer (score 3):

`.=` is to `.` what `+=` is to `+` like in C.

```
$a += 4;
```

is like:

```
$a = $a + 4;
```

```
$a .= "x";
```

is like:

```
$a = $a . "x";
```

Same as with most operators.

`.` itself is the string concatenation operator so `$key .= $descriptions[$i];` appends `$descriptions[$i]`, shorter and more efficient than:

```
$key = $key . $descriptions[$i];
```

or

```
$key = "$key$descriptions[$i]";
```

Like all operators it's described in `perldoc perlop`:

> ### Assignment Operators
>
> "=" is the ordinary assignment operator.
>
> Assignment operators work as in C. That is,
>
> ```
>  $x += 2;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>  $x = $x + 2;
> ```
>
> although without duplicating any side effects that dereferencing the
> lvalue might trigger, such as from "tie()". Other assignment operators
> work similarly. The following are recognized:
>
> ```
>  **=    +=    *=    &=    &.=    <<=    &&=
>         -=    /=    |=    |.=    >>=    ||=
>         .=    %=    ^=    ^.=           //=
>               x=
> ```
>
> Although these are grouped by family, they all have the precedence of
> assignment. These combined assignment operators can only operate on
> scalars, whereas the ordinary assignment operator can assign to arrays,
> hashes, lists and even references. (See "Context" and "List value
> constructors" in perldata, and "Assigning to References" in perlref.)

Comment: This wasn't very clear to me :-) Luckily it's explained here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/miscellaneous_operators_example.htm

Comment: Only useful 50% of the time, i.e. when you have `$x` and want `$x` updated with `$y` string-appended on to the right end (assuming L-to-R language here). Not useful if you have `$x` and you want `$x` updated with `$y` string-prepended on the left end.

Answer (score -1):

**Was your original code example Perl(5), or actually Perl6, a.k.a. Raku?**

In year 2000, the Perl folk announced an ambitious re-write to the Perl language, then currently at version 5.6.0. The new version (Perl6) was not anticipated to be backwards-compatible with Perl5, and since the 2015 release of the Rakudo compiler, that plan has held in practice: Perl6 (a.k.a. Raku) and Perl5 are distinct languages.

Perl6 was renamed Raku in 2019.

The `.` dot in Perl5 denotes string-concatenation, but in Perl6/Raku it underwent major revision. Similar to other languages, Perl6/Raku has the `.` dot denote ***method-chaining***. So the following Perl6/Raku code strings (no pun intended) three methods together with the `.` dot operator:

In the Raku REPL:

```perl
admin@mbp ~ % raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
[0] > (1..10).grep( * %% 2).reverse.put;
10 8 6 4 2
```

*[ What does that mean for string-concatenation in Per6/Raku? String-concatenation is now accomplished with the `~` tilde operator, so `~=` is the Perl6/Raku equivalent of `.=` from/in Perl(5) ].*

Anyway, because string-concatenation and method-chaining are distinct in Perl6/Raku, there is less confusion for those persons coming over from other languages.

#### Now about that `.=` operator:

In Perl6/Raku, `=` is the ordinary assignment operator. To declare a variable in Perl6/Raku, you generally use the `my` (or `our`) keywords.

```perl
[1] > my $x = 'apple banana carrot';
apple banana carrot
```

Once declared, you can both 1. call a method and 2. re-assign to the new value with `.=`:

```perl
[2] > $x .= uc;
APPLE BANANA CARROT
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```perl
[2] > $x = $x.uc;
APPLE BANANA CARROT
```

Needless to say, you'll see your greatest savings in memory, etc., quickly updating/overwriting larger objects like arrays:

```perl
[3] > my @array = 1..100;
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100]
[4] > @array.grep: *.is-prime;
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97)
[5] > put @array;
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100]
```

Above, `@array` retains its original value until you overwrite it:

```perl
[6] > @array .= grep: *.is-prime;
[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97]
[7] > put @array;
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

http://blob.perl.org/perlweb/dev/perl6/talks/2001/dconway-Perl6.pdf
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_.=
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#methodop_.=
https://raku.org

Comment: A downvote indicates room for improvement. Please inform me as to how the above post can be improved. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, when I do `perl6 -e 'my $key = "x"; my $i = 1;  my $descriptions = (&lc, &uc); $key .= $descriptions[$i]; put $key'`, I get a *`Missing infix inside []`* error. How would you make the OP's code work in `perl6`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I would use the sub version instead:  `perl6 -e 'my $key = "x"; my $i := 1;  my $descriptions = (&lc, &uc); $key = $descriptions[$i]($key); put $key;'` returns: `X`. So far, I haven't come up with an answer using .= and that might have something to do with [Dotty_infix_precedence](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Dotty_infix_precedence).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The closest I come to the OP's code with Perl6/Raku is something like `perl6 -MURL -ne 'my $url = URL.new($_); $url .= hostname; .raku.put for $url;'   file`, where the `.=` takes the original 9-slot `$url` object and overwrites it with the value of the `hostname` slot.

Comment: What makes you think it might have been Raku instead of Perl as the question says? The comments say it's not accepted syntax in Raku, and you yourself had to rewrite it to something different to make it valid in Raku? Just because they share some ancestry (and a confusing naming history), doesn't mean pushing Raku on every question on Perl is on topic.